# How to configure docker-compose Kafka connect CDC setup with schema-registy?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to set up `docker-compose` setup with

- Kafka broker
- zookeper
- debezium kafka connector
- schema-registry

using

- confluen kafka image
- debezium/connect:1.4
- confluent cp-schema-registry

Schema registry keeps giving error
`... connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:29092) could not be established...`

Obviously trying to connect to *localhost*, but Kafka broker is in its own container in `docker-compose` setup.

I just cannot find any examples or documentation how to configure schema-registry.

All examples use config like:

```yaml
      schema-registry:
        image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.5.3
        environment:
          - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL=zookeeper:2181
          - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME=schema-registry
          - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS=http://schema-registry:8081,http://localhost:8081
        ports:
          - 8081:8081
        depends_on: [zookeeper, kafka]
```

ERROR Server died unexpectedly: (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.***rest***.SchemaRegistryMain) on kafkastore.bootrap.servers ...

schemaregisty.rest ???

Comment: Use `SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS` with the kafka address instead, not Zookeeper https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one/blob/7.5.0-post/cp-all-in-one-community/docker-compose.yml

Comment: Also, the error is probably coming from your `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` variable on the kafka image, which you'll need to share.

Comment: I am still missing something here : "org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Must configure at least one bootstrap connection method, either kafkastore.connection.url or kafkastore.bootstrap.services."

Comment: "Also, the error is probably coming from your KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS variable on the kafka image, which you'll need to share." -- I did not quite get this. How do I need to "share" it ? It is defined at kafka container config at docker-compose.yaml.

Comment: [Edit] the post, please. We cannot see what you've defined on your whole compose file.

Comment: Still I find this kind of weird: "must configure at least one bootstrap connection method"... my special one time error message. Nothing can  be found by googling.

Comment: Your edit includes `kafkastore.bootrap.servers` and `bootstrap` is missing an `s`. Regarding `schemaregistry.rest`, yes, that is the main Java class that is ran.. . Here's another compose file you could try https://github.com/rayanegouda/medium/blob/main/step1/docker-compose.yaml#L67

Comment: Now it works with SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL=broker:9092. Thank you very much for help :)